# Generate Google sheet with selection from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I want to make a list of vegetarians in Document 2 from information in Document 1.

Document 1 Columns A and B.

```
Bill    Meat

Jane    Veg

Tony    Meat

Sarah   Veg
```

I want Document 2 to search Document 1 and make a list that looks like:

```
Jane   Veg

Sarah  Veg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER('Document 1'!A:B, 'Document 1'!B:B="Veg")
```

[image: 0]